# SIP2 not support with TLS1.2 Protocal in php

Tags: php, ssl, tls1.2

I am using SSL connection to connecting to the sip2 server. but now server upgrade with TLS1.2

We use this below class(sip2.class.php) to connect SIP2 server and that class use ssl connect. Any suggestion on how will connect using TLS1.2 with below script using PHP

https://github.com/the-codepunker/php-sip2/blob/master/sip2.class.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue using SIP2 wrapper class

https://libraries.io/github/tzeumer/Sip2Wrapper